# what does the methodology in picture indicates? Python programming

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am trying to implement the process as shown in the below image for text summarization:
[image: Concept image.]

I have understood that the second step is the generating the dependency graph using the Stanford Parser. Here is the code:

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
path_to_jar = 'path_to/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser.jar'
path_to_models_jar = 'path_to/stanford-parser-full-2014-08-27/stanford-parser-3.4.1-models.jar'
dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)

result = dependency_parser.raw_parse('I shot an elephant in my sleep')
dep = result.next()
list(dep.triples())
```

But the part what I am not able to get is the third and fourth. Kindly help me understand it. If possible what is the possible implementation of the third and fourth. Kindly, help me.

Comment: Is this picture a part of some text? Did you read it?

Comment: The text may be a bit small but surely it is readable?

Comment: @DYZ Yes I did. You can read it from here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=aPHsBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=stanford+text+graph+summar&source=bl&ots=VluSuGI7Uf&sig=oxi6QOssXKSr2y3KbBak3vIBCZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtovT4q8TVAhVKNI8KHe3ZCSAQ6AEIYjAJ#v=onepage&q=stanford%20text%20graph%20summar&f=false

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes it is ..

Comment: @DYZ As the text from the link depicts that the concept is related to multi document.. I am trying to achieve it for single sentence.

Comment: I am thinking of like a dependency based sentence compression or concise sentence.

Comment: I hope that my point is clear. Right?

Comment: I am looking for answer. I didn't understood why people downvote with no comment why the downvote is?

Comment: Is there no one to answer the question I asked?

Comment: People may be downvoting because the question is far from clear. There is not enough context to even attempt an answer. Anyway the 'WordNet' and 'VerbNet' looks like they are two databases. That's my two pence.